# How to pass string parameters from c++ com to c#?

Tags: c#, c++, com

I have c++ code that has a parameter like this:

```
STDMETHODIMP TVinaImpl::test(BSTR Param1)
{
  try
  {
      Param1=(L"test1");
  }
  catch(Exception &e)
  {
    return Error(e.Message.c_str(), IID_IVina);
  }
  return S_OK;
}
```

I use c++ builder:
[image]
When I call this com dll function in c# it shows me the error:

```
IntPtr a = new IntPtr();
vina.test(a);
```

it is null and did not get the value.
How can I pass variable from C# to c++ com and pass back it?

Answer (score 2):

Since `Param1` is declared as an `[in, out]` parameter, you need to declare it as a pointer to a BSTR: `STDMETHODIMP TVinaImpl::test(BSTR* Param1)`

Furthermore, you cannot simply assign a string literal to a BSTR. The correct way is to allocate memory using `SysAllocString`: `*Param1 = SysAllocString(L"test1");`

Comment: If there any way to avoid using SysAllocString in c++?

Comment: Unfortunately that's not possible. BSTRs are managed by COM and always need to be allocated from its memory allocator. If automation compatibility is not required, you might consider using a simple `wchar_t*` instead.

Comment: Is there any way to allocate memory in client side (for example in c# ) and pass parameter by reference to c++ method?

Comment: Yes, that's possible. You will need to change your definition of Param1 to `wchar_t*`, as indicated in my previous comment: `[in, out, string] wchar_t** Param1`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you declare the argument Param1 as `[out, retval]`.  You are not using Param1 as any kind of input.

```
STDMETHODIMP TVinaImpl::test(BSTR* Param1)
{
  try
  {
      *Param1= SysAllocString(L"test1");
  }
  catch(Exception &e)
  {
    return Error(e.Message.c_str(), IID_IVina);
  }
  return S_OK;
}
```

Then when you call the function from C# it is just,

```
string s = vina.test();
```

The .Net runtime manages marshalling of data from .Net to COM and vice versa.

Comment: You said right, but when I want return multi parameters to send my function and return all of them, How can I do that. each function just can get one return value.